# Could you explain svg tags in website?

Tags: html

I found website that i like, and i download the html source code 
I have understand all html source except svg code in homepage can you explain this all numbers means?

you can just explain numbers meaning in svg tags. thank you :)

this is html source: http://1drv.ms/1FPR9Iw

Comment: that is similar To XML you can learn easily.. it is basically used to generate tree structures and more in graphics..

Answer (score 1):

Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is the description of an image as an application of the Extensible Markup Language (XML). Any program such as a Web browser that recognizes XML can display the image using the information provided in the SVG format. Different from a raster graphicsscalable part of the term emphasizes that vector graphic images can easily be made scalable (whereas an image specified in raster graphics is a fixed-size bitmap). Thus, the SVG format enables the viewing of an image on a computer display of any size and resolution, whether a tiny LCD screen in a cell phone or a large CRT display in a workstation. In addition to ease of size reduction and enlargement, SVG allows text within images to be recognized as such, so that the text can be located by a search engine and easily translated into other languages.

Being a vector graphics format SVG is mostly useful for vector type diagrams like:

Two-dimensional graphs in an X,Y coordinate system.
Column charts, pie charts etc.
Scalable icons and logos for web, tablet and mobile apps and webapps.
Architecture and design diagrams
etc.

so the number are co-ordinates for your shape

To know more about it and how it's useful and how we should use it please follow below links

you can read more about it [Here](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Scalable-Vector-Graphics) and [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Svg ( `Scalable Vector Graphics`) defines graphics in `xml` format. you can read more about it here: [svg w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp).